# Android Volley - Async testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-volley, wiremock

I am using the Volley library to make HTTP requests.

I want to make a test where I stub the HTTP response with WireMock. The WireMock stubbing part is not a problem but I can't think of a solution that allows me to wait for the async Volley request to finish.

```
@Test
public void callOnSuccessWhenGoodResponse()
{
    // WireMock stubbing...

    myVolleyClass.signup(infos, mockedCallback); // Async operation

    // Have to wait here for the async operation to finish

    Mockito.verify(mockedCallback).onSuccess(token);
}
```

How do I wait for the async operation to finish ?

I've tried with a `CountDownLatch` like that :

```
@Test
public void callOnSuccessWhenGoodResponse()
{
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    MyCallback callback = new MyCallBack()
    {
        @Override
        void onSuccess()
        {
            latch.countDown();
        }

        void onError()
        {
            fail("Expected onSuccess but got onError");
        }
    };

    // WireMock stubbing...

    myVolleyClass.signup(infos, callback); // Async operation

    latch.await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    assertEquals(0, latch.getCount());
}
```

but the `await()` blocks the current thread and Volley executes the callback that we give it on the UI Thread which I guess would be the thread the test is running on. So the `countdown()` would never execute in time.

The best solution would be to have Volley make its requests synchronously during this test but I don't know if it's possible and what to mock. Any hints ?

Comment: No one ? I still can't figure out a solution.